# Doesn't float properly - boxes everywhere

Tags: html, css

I have the following css:

```
.horizontal-holder1{
float:left;
width:88px;
height:98px;
margin-bottom:15px;
border:1px solid #bdbdbd;
background-color:grey;
}
.white-holder{
width:88px;
height:49px;
background-color:white;
float:left;

.yellow-holder{
width:88px;
height:49px;
background-color:#FFF8DC;
float:left;
} 
.player-holder{
width:60px;
height:49px;
float:left;
}
.score-holder{
width:28px;
height:49px;
float:left;
}
```

And the following html:

```
<div class="horizontal-holder1">
    <div class="white-holder">
        <div class="player-holder">
            <? echo $data['username']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="score-holder">
            0
        <div>
    </div>
    <div class="yellow-holder">
        <div class="player-holder">
            <? echo $data['username']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="score-holder">
            0
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the yellow holder doesn't float below the white holder, it goes to the right.

Can anyone see a reason for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible issue with the syntax on "score-holder"

```
<div class="score-holder">
    0
<div>
```

the closing `<div>` tag has no end-tag slash (`/`)

looks okay once the end-tags are fixed: **[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/zcJk7/)**

Comment: I have spent a long time tracking the error to that snippet of code and still didn't notice that. How irritating!

Answer (score 0):

1. Properly close the `.score-holder`
2. It's a good practise to name your classes by their purpose not appearance (`.yellow-holder` `.second-team-holder`).
3. Why do you put `float:left` everywhere?
4. Add `}` after `.yellow-holder` CSS definition

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `/` in some of your closing tags, and a `}` in your CSS.

```
<div class="horizontal-holder1">
    <div class="white-holder">
        <div class="player-holder">
            <? echo $data['username']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="score-holder">
            0
        </div> <!-- here -->
    </div>
    <div class="yellow-holder">
        <div class="player-holder">
            <? echo $data['username']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="score-holder">
            0
        </div> <!-- and here! -->
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.horizontal-holder1{
float:left;
width:88px;
height:98px;
margin-bottom:15px;
border:1px solid #bdbdbd;
background-color:grey;
}
.white-holder{
width:88px;
height:49px;
background-color:white;
float:left;
} /* whoops! */
.yellow-holder{
width:88px;
height:49px;
background-color:#FFF8DC;
float:left;
} 
.player-holder{
width:60px;
height:49px;
float:left;
}
.score-holder{
width:28px;
height:49px;
float:left;
}
```

All fixed: http://cssdesk.com/LT5tL